# Node wrangler is stacking menus on top of each other?

Tags: shaders, add-on

Why is node wrangler stacking the menus on top of each other when it comes into the shading window. Here's a pic.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting the menus and dragging them off of each other?

Comment: yes, that works but until recently it would lay them out side by side, no need for additional work:) I wonder if I should remove it and reinstall node wrangler

Comment: That's a good idea. If that doesn't work, I'm sure some of the other members can help. I can't offer much advice because I'm still learning to use the Shading section but I wish you all the best.

Comment: If you use the Node Wrangler's Ctrl-Shift-T hotkey to select the materials everything should be neatly laid out in Frames but that obviously hasn't happened here for some reason. If you just want to spread out the nodes you could use the built-in Node Arrange addon but that shouldn't be necessary in this case. You should have version 3.47 of the wrangler automatically installed if you're using Blender 4+.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assistance, I updated Blender from 4.0 to the latest and node wrangler is working wonderfully!